# How to make solverstudio (pulp and cbc) report out conflict constraints in case of infeasble?

Tags: pulp

I am using solverstudio (pulp and cbc). How to make the solver report out the conflict constraints? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is infeasible, then technically ALL of your constraints are in conflict. However, for whatever intermediate solution was found before the solver returned Infeasible, you can try this to see which constraints were violated:

```
for c in lp.constraints.itervalues():
    if not c.valid(0):
        print c.name, c.value()
```