# Check constraint PULP python 3

Tags: python-3.x, constraints, pulp, feasibility

I am using pulp to solve a lineal problem in python, I have thousands of constraints, so I can not check each constraints,  and my result with some constraints is "Infeasible".

Each restriction has an associated name, how can I know which constraint is not feasible? (In order to fix up the input data or the constraint)

I found this information but the solution code does not work:

[How to make solverstudio (pulp and cbc) report out conflict constraints in case of infeasble?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43861880/how-to-make-solverstudio-pulp-and-cbc-report-out-conflict-constraints-in-case)

I am using python 3.6 64 bits.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @F. Riquelme.  Please let us know how the solution code does not work form you and what you have already tried.

Comment: I try this:                                                                                                        
 for c in lp.constraints.itervalues():
    if not c.valid(0):
        print c.name, c.value(),                                                                                             tomorrow i will add more details.

Comment: I prefer using slack variables. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62754051/pulp-constraints-when-probelm-is-infeasible/62771338#62771338